# Overwriting auto load for a major mode

Tags: emacs, major-mode

I want to set auto mode for files that have a particular name like this:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\particular-file-name\\'" . some-major-mode))
```

This seems to work, but when there is another auto mode preset for the same file name, then the preset one seems to have priority, and my setting is ignored. How can I override that or disable the preset? Particularly, I want to have all files named `config` to have a certain major mode, but `Conf[Unix]` mode seems to have priority over my setting.

Comment: Add the conflicted file name, the entry of `auto-mode-alist` that you expect, and the entry that you actually get.

Comment: @abo-abo **As I wrote explicitly**, the file name is `config`, the conflicting mode is `Conf[Unix]`.

Comment: No need to put half of a single line it bold, I don't have ADD.
You still haven't added the modes that I asked. `some-major-mode` and "certain major mode"
are not valid modes, and I'd prefer not to guess a mode's name from string description "Conf[Unix]".

Comment: @sawa Please show your *exact* code, not some approximation thereof.  `auto-mode-alist` entries are used in order of appearance, so your own entries will take precedence over built-in ones.  As such, it's likely that you made a mistake in the entry, which we can only discover if we see your real code.

Comment: @lunaryorn The exact code is `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\config\\" . ruby-mode))`.

Comment: It was actually `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\config\\'" . ruby-mode))`.

Answer (score 3):

It probably happens due to

```
;;;###autoload
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '(...))
```

in the major-mode el file.  The autoload instructions are evaluated after `~/.emacs`.

You can try to load your setup in the `after-init-hook`

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
      (function (lambda()
          (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '(...)))))
```

It might be better when `;;;###autoload` users would **append** their entries to `auto-mode-list` (setting the *APPEND* option of `add-to-list`).  But this seems to be uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your regexp, it would not match the filename ("config") the correct regexp is

1) If you want to match a file named 'config'

```
"config\\'"
```

2) If you want to match files with extension '.config'

```
"\\.config\\'"
```

In case you are wondering `\'` matches end of the string. In your regexp the string `\\` translates to a `\` in regexp.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in what I posted. The regex that I have is actually as you suggested. I have `"\\config\\'"`.

Comment: @sawa, I just checked the above works for me. Does it not work for you even when you start emacs with emacs -Q. If you are trying to match file name `config` remove the leading `\\`.